# CMake returns linux/videodev.h not exist while build opencv

Tags: make, opencv

Got problem while building `opencv` accoding to [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/):

```
Determining if the include file linux/videodev.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_affcb/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_affcb.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_affcb.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_affcb.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_affcb.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/videodev.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
```

.....
.....

I just did cd linux in order to look file videodev.h is there, but system can't find such directory. File `/usr/include/linux/videodev.h` exist on my system. I suppose compiler is not able to find it. How to solve such problem?

Answer (score 0):

this would do:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
```